# How to automate the deletion of several rows that are not contiguous

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I am trying to traversal rows in worksheet and I want to delete some rows meet certain conditions; e.g. delete the rows which column 2 is blank;

I have tried :
use foreach to traversal and then delete, but when the row is deleted and the range below the row is shiftup, some rows will missed:

```
 foreach(Range row in usedRange)
    {
        if(Cells[row.Row, 2] is blank)
            row.EntireRow.Delete(xlShiftUp);
    }
```

So, can I markup all the rows need to delete first, and then delete all the marked rows in one time?
Is there any ways like this or any other ways to fullfill my need?

Thanks a lot;

Comment: use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`, loop from the last row to the first row backwards using `Step -1`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this. this looks into the range A7:D20 and deletes all rows with empty 2nd column **in the range**

```
Dim usedRange As Range
Set usedRange = Range("A7:D20")

For i = usedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If usedRange(i, 2) = "" Then
        usedRange(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your advice, I tried your method with c# and works fine. And I found another solution, to traversal usedRange.count, and when the row is deleted, execute i-- , also works fine.